# How do I read a text-file's content from it's shared Dropbox link in Swift 4.2 (without downloading)?

Tags: cocoa, dropbox, swift4.2

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to output a simple text-file's content from it's shared Dropbox link (without downloading) through Swift 4.2.

For Example:

```
let url = URL(string: "https://www.dropbox.com/s/rokwv82h54ogwy1/test.txt?dl=0")!
// the dropbox link above is a shared link so anyone can view it
    
do {
                
    let content = try String(contentsOf: url)
    print("File Content:   \(content)")
} catch let error as NSError {
                
    print("\(error)")
}
```

When I run this code I get this error:

**Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “test.txt” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file."**(there's more to the error but it's quite big)

Can anyone help me out please? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There's more to the error but it's quite big

Do not strip error messages. If you don't know to fix this issue, you probably don't know what to strip to keep it valuable.

## How to fix your problem

- Select target
- Switch to *Signing & Capabilities* tab
- *App Sandbox* - *Network* - enable *Outgoing Connections (Client)*

[image]

- Change the URL (`dl=0`) to (`dl=1`)

  - `0` = display web page with a preview and download link
  - `1` = do not display any web page, just serve the file

```swift
let url = URL(string: "https://www.dropbox.com/s/rokwv82h54ogwy1/test.txt?dl=1")!
// Change dl=0 to dl=1                                                       ^
    
do {
    let content = try String(contentsOf: url)
    print("File Content: \(content)")
} catch let error as NSError {
    print("\(error)")
}
```

Run again and you'll get:

```
File Content:   
This is a test. If you can read this, you have passed! :)
```

Do not use `String(contentsOf: url)`, because it's not async and it will block the main thread (UI).

Asynchronous example - imagine you have a view controller with one text field (label) and you'd like to display the file content there:

```swift
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {
    @IBOutlet var textField: NSTextField!
    
    override func viewWillAppear() {
        super.viewWillAppear()
        textField.stringValue = "Loading ..."
        loadRemoteFile()
    }
    
    func loadRemoteFile() {
        let url = URL(string: "https://www.dropbox.com/s/rokwv82h54ogwy1/test.txt?dl=1")!
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, _, error in
            // Following code is not called on the main thread. If we'd like to
            // modify UI elements, we have to dispatch our code on the main thread.
            // Hence the DispatchQueue.main.async {}.
            
            if let error = error {
                print("Failed with error: \(error)")
                DispatchQueue.main.async { self.textField.stringValue = "Failed" }
                return
            }

            guard let data = data,
                  let content = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) else {
                print("Failed to decode data as an UTF-8 string")
                DispatchQueue.main.async { self.textField.stringValue = "Failed" }
                return
            }
            
            print("Content: \(content)")
            DispatchQueue.main.async { self.textField.stringValue = content }
        }
        
        // At this point, we have a task which will download the file, but the task
        // is not running. Every task is initially suspended.
        
        task.resume() // Start the background task
        
        // At this point, your program normally continues, because the download
        // is executed in the background (not on the main thread).
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, kinda scratching my head as I read this. Is it possible you could provide some examples?

Comment: Ok sweet, thanks. Just one more thing, how do I unwrap the file if I can’t use “String(contentsOf:)”? Hope this isn’t too much to ask.

Comment: Did add async example. Glad it works, but now, please, go and read the [App Sandbox](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/app_sandbox) stuff to learn why.